# How to animate a Div from left to current position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Guys I am trying to move a car from left to the current position of the DIV.

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JUNBT/5/

Code

```
setTimeout(function(){

 var  pos = $('#parentx').offset() - ('.car1').offset() ;

   $(".car1").animate({left: pos}, 2000);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you want that I will show you how you can fix **your** code?

Comment: Check the Developer Tools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox) console for JavaScript errors (`Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function`) first!

Comment: You have some problems in your code (forgot `$` in `('.car1')` for example). Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/JUNBT/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the car to some default position (just change the `left` value in css) and then check for the left offset of the `.car1 parent`  and animate the `left` to that value.

```
function moveCar() {
    var newPos = $(".car1").parent().offset().left;
    $('.car1').animate({left: newPos + "px"}, 2000);
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjp8x2mk/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This. It will work :)

```
div.car1
{

 transition:2s;
 -webkit-transition:2s;
 -moz-transition:2s;
 position:absolute;
 right:calc(100% - 100px);
}

div.car1:hover
{
right:0px;
}
```